# Translating the $\frac{u_x}{x}+\frac{u_y}{y}+\frac{u_z}{z}=\frac{u}{1-u}\quad u(\sqrt{y^2+z^2},y,z)=g(y)$ PDE into Mathematica notation?

Tags: differential-equations

This may be silly, but I am trying to find solutions to the following differential equation:

$$\frac{u_x}{x}+\frac{u_y}{y}+\frac{u_z}{z}=\frac{u}{1-u}\hspace{2cm} u(\sqrt{y^2+z^2},y,z)=g(y)$$

On Mathematica. My trouble is that I am a bit confused with the notation on Mathematica. How does that translates into Mathematica? I tried the following:

```
DSolve[{

   D[u[x, y, z], x]/x + D[u[x, y, z], y]/y + D[u[x, y, z], z]/z == u[x, y, z]/(1 - u[x, y,z]),

  u[0, y, z] == Sqrt[y^2 + z^2],
  u[x, 0, z] == y,
  u[x, y, 0] == z,
  u[x,y,z] == g[y]

}, u, {x, y, z}]
```

Is that correct? I'm a bit confused. This doesn't yield solutions.

Comment: I do not understand `u[x, 0, z] == y`  since `y=0` why not write  `u[x, 0, z] == 0` ? same for `u[x, y, 0] == z`  is this not saying `u[x, y, 0] == 0`? before worrying about BC. Mathematica can't solve this nonlinear PDE. `pde = D[u[x, y, z], x]/x + D[u[x, y, z], y]/y + D[u[x, y, z], z]/z ==  u[x, y, z]/(1 - u[x, y, z]); DSolve[pde, u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]`   says `Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.`  so I think you need to use `NDSolve` once you figure what the correct BC's are and fix `g[y]`

Comment: Your equation are not compatible. You write `u[x,y,z] == g[y]` what says, that u is only a function of y.  But then you specify:  `u[0, y, z] == Sqrt[y^2 + z^2]` e.t.c.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by reducing equation to the linear form with substitution $v=\ln u-u$ as follows

```
DSolve[
 D[v[x, y, z], x]/x + D[v[x, y, z], y]/y + D[v[x, y, z], z]/z == 1, 
 v[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]

Out[]= {{v[x, y, z] -> 
   x^2/2 + C[1][1/2 (-x^2 + y^2), 1/2 (-x^2 + z^2)]}}
```

Second equation means that $v(\sqrt{y^2+z^2},y,z)=\ln g(y)-g(y)$. We can transform general solution on the surface $x^2=y^2+z^2$ as

```
(x^2/2 + C[1][1/2 (-x^2 + y^2), 1/2 (-x^2 + z^2)]) /. {x^2 -> 
   y^2 + z^2}
 
Out[]= 1/2 (y^2 + z^2) + C[1][-(z^2/2), -(y^2/2)]
```

To satisfy second equation we can suggest that `C[1]` is a linear function on a first argument, $C[1]=-z^2/2+f(y)$. Therefore, $f(y)=-y^2/2+\ln g(y)-g(y)$. Finally we have
$$v=x^2/2+1/2 (-x^2 + y^2)+f(\sqrt {z^2-x^2})$$